# Associative style arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to assign an object in the style of an associate array in JS but it's failing, saying 'task.id' is undefined. Why is this?

```
var response = Object();
$('.task-list').each(function() {
  response[this.id][$('#' + this.id).sortable('toArray')];
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referencing the object as a two dimensional array.

You should do it more like this:

```
var response = {};
$(".task-list").each(function () {
    response[this.id] = $(this).sortable('toArray');
}
```

Also, when you say the error is "task.id is undefined", do you mean "this.id is undefined"?  If you are selecting elements based on class, they may not have an explicit id.

```
<span class="task-list">myTask</span>
```

You may want to include an id:

```
<span class="task-list" id="myTask">myTask</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a property that you haven't created yet. Although it's not actually clear what you are trying to do from your example. I'm assuming you want to set the value of `response[this.id]` to `$('#' + this.id).sortable('toArray')`?

Try this instead:

```
var response = {};
$('.task-list').each(function() {
    response[this.id] = $(this).sortable('toArray');
});
```

Also changed it to use `$(this)` instead of `$('#' + this.id)` as it's cleaner imo.